# Remote Event Receiver Write to List

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I want to create a remote event receiver that is triggered when a list item in a specific list on all subsites is updated, and then write a value from that list to a list on the top-level site. Is a remote event receiver the best way to do this?

I have Visual Studio 2013 Professional installed and have looked into the remote event receiver but I'm not great at C#.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com). You can create simple flow that is triggered by updating the list item and add an action that creates/updates the item in other list.

Of course the things that can be done with MS Flow are limited, but it should definitely cover your scenario.

If you want to create the remote event receiver, you will have to deploy it somewhere (Azure) and possibly have additional costs. MS Flow comes with o365 subscription.

Comment: Thanks @Damjan A colleague had previously mentioned Flow so I'll look into it.

Comment: The one issue with Flow is that it always runs under the context of the user that created it. So Linton no one else will be able to see or edit the flow besides yourself. You may want to look into Logic Apps as well, they are similar to Flow but geared more towards developers and power users.